# Intellij right-click context menu disappears infuriatingly

Tags: linux, linux-mint, context-menu, intellij-idea

OS: Linux Minut 18.3, Intellij "Community 2020.1 EAP"

I've just started using Intellij, after using Eclipse for many years.

I've naturally searched on this problem: the few relevant hits seem to date from years ago.

What happens: I right-click (this is another bugbear: I hate being obliged to use the mouse for ANYTHING, and Shift-F10 doesn't work): the context menu displays... I try to move the focus to something in the menu... and - woosh - the menu has gone.

Nor does it help to keep the right button depressed: the menu still disappears on "single items"... by that I mean menu items which are not followed by "...". With items which obviously lead on to another submenu the context menu does NOT disappear.

As suggested from my searching, I have tried tweaking the File --> Settings --> Keymap settings. But nothing has worked so far.

It's odd when you come across something like this: is no-one else experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this and remembered an old fix from years ago:

1. Go to Preferences | Keymap.
2. In the filter box type `Context menu`.
3. Right click on Other | Show Context Menu.
4. Select `Remove Button 3`.
5. Click Apply and OK to exit the dialog.

Your right click pop-up menu should start working as normal once again.